# Data Class and properties from other Data Class

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm downloading few lists (RawAlbum, RawPhoto) from the web and I want to use properties from them to create another list. Then I want to use it to make a recyclerview.

So that's how it looks. It is the ListItem:

```
@Parcelize
data class ListItem(
val id: Int,
val title: String,
val albumTitle: String,
val thumbnailUrl: String
) : Parcelable
```

So I want to use the id and title from the RawAlbum. While the albumTitle and thumbnailUrl from the RawPhoto.

RawAlbum:

```
@Parcelize
@Entity(tableName = "albums")
data class RawAlbum(
@PrimaryKey
val id: Int,
val userId: Int,
val title: String
) : Parcelable
```

RawPhoto:

```
@Parcelize
@Entity(tableName = "photos")
data class RawPhoto(
@PrimaryKey
val id: Int,
val albumId: Int,
val title: String,
val url: String,
val thumbnailUrl: String
) : Parcelable
```

Comment: What’s your question?

Comment: How to assign properties from the RawAlbum and RawPhoto to the ListItem? In a recyclerview item I want to use properties from both.